# gradlew assembleDebug fails because of transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

When i build my android application using "Build->Build Project" on android studio. it works fine. But when i run:

```
gradlew assembleDebug
```

from terminal. Build fails and prints this message:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
```

What is the difference between two methods? How can i solve this problem because i have to create my .apk file using gradle scripts.

Comment: Did you try clean the project with `gradlew clean`?

Comment: yes i did, i run "gradlew clean" before assembleDebug

Comment: You probably have a duplicate library there somewhere. to track run `./gradlew yourBuildVariantName --debug` from the command line. first failure should be your offending library

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` files.